# SQL Query. How can I combine these two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

```
Table A 
|user_id| |type     |revenues|
101,       comic,    10
101,       adventure,30
101,       comic,    10
102,       romantic, 20
```

and

```
Table B

|type    |
comic
adventure
romantic
animate
```

where Table B contains the entire book type. Table A contains the transactions. How to combine the two tables into a new one so that it shows each person's transactions. (Note: 1, For the book_types a person didn't buy, the revenues should be zero. 2, sum(revenues) for the same user_id and type combination). For example, a new table should be like:

```
Table New
101, comic,     20
101, adventure, 30
101, romantic,  0
101, animate,   0
102, comic,     0
102, adventure, 0
102, romantic,  20
102, animate,   0
```

To create the tables, one can use the following code:

```
create table A(usr_id integer, book_type varchar(100), revenues integer);
create table B(book_type varchar(100));
insert into A(usr_id, book_type, revenues) values(101, "comic", 10);
insert into A(usr_id, book_type, revenues) values(101, "comic", 10);
insert into A(usr_id, book_type, revenues) values(101, "adventure",30); 
insert into A(usr_id, book_type, revenues) values(102, "romantic",20); 

insert into B(book_type) values("comic");
insert into B(book_type) values("adventure");
insert into B(book_type) values("romantic");
insert into B(book_type) values("animate");
```

If there is only one kind of user_id, I can come up with a solution (see below). But I don't know how to deal with the cases when there are many user_id.

```
select case when tmp.user_id is NUll then 101 else tmp.usr_id END,  
B.book_type, case when tmp.revenues is NULL then 0 else tmp.revenues 
END
from 
(
select usr_id, book_type, sum(revenues) as revenues
from A
group by usr_id, book_type
) tmp 
right join B on tmp.book_type = B.book_type
```

Comment: Please show what you can do & explain re being stuck. Please don't ask us to do your (home)work. See [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the previous answer, but includes the summing of the revenues for a given `user_id` and `type` combination:

```
SELECT q1.user_id, q1.type, IFNULL(SUM(revenues),0) 
FROM
    (
     SELECT DISTINCT user_id, TableB.type
     FROM TableA CROSS JOIN TableB
     ) q1 
LEFT JOIN TableA ON q1.user_id = TableA.user_id AND q1.type = TableA.type
GROUP BY q1.user_id, q1.type
ORDER BY q1.user_id;
```

The approach is to:

1. cross-join the two tables to generate all possible user_id and type pairings
2. join between the new cross-join temp table and the revenues from Table A
3. sum the revenues for user_id and type combinations, or give 0 in the case of nulls

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2179a/29).

Comment: brilliant! very succinct and useful explanation. Thanks

Comment: glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of CROSS and LEFT join as shown below to get your desired output.

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=55c6edd2195bf282c7082b4ee7226c25)

```
SELECT A.user_id,B.type,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(C.revenues) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE C.revenues END
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
    FROM Table_A) A
CROSS JOIN Table_B B
LEFT JOIN Table_A C ON A.user_id = C.user_id AND B.type = C.type
ORDER BY A.user_id,B.type
```